# ActionListener works but painting doesn't

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, paintcomponent

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Game extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    int wx;
    int rx = 10;
    int rx2 = 10;
    int carx = 10;
    int velX = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Frogger");
        window.add(new Game());
        window.pack();
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);


    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        carx+=velX;
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        repaint();
        g.setColor(new Color(173, 216, 230));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600); //background
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.fillRect(0, 525, 800, 75); //start
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 30); //end
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 275, 800, 250); //street
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
            g.fillRect(rx, 450, 20, 10);
            rx += 50;
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
            g.fillRect(rx2, 375, 20, 10);
            rx2 += 50;
        }
        g.fillRect(carx, 477, 60, 30);
        t.start();

    }

}
```

I am trying to make a Frogger game and am having trouble creating the traffic. I am able to make a car move across the street but the lines separating the lanes are shown for a millisecond and then disappear after I run the program. The street, river, start, and end all show up as I want them to. How do I make the lane lines not disappear?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something here but surely calling `repaint` in the `paintComponent` method will cause an infinite loop?

Comment: @rodit I took out the repaint but it still did the same thing. I figured out that it has to do with the Timer and t.start() though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with what you are doing.

Firstly, you are calling t.start() every time the component is drawn. This is unnecessary. Instead of doing this, create a boolean value determining whether it is the first frame and start it then. Here is how you can do this:

```
boolean firstFrame = true;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(firstFrame){
        t.start();
        firstFrame = false;
    }
    //rest of render code...
}
```

Now for your question of how to stop the lines disappearing. You seem to store the integers `rx` and `rx2` as members of the Game class. This means when you add to them, they stay added until reset. Therefore, every frame, you must reset `rx` and `rx2` to 10.

At the end of `paintComponent`, add this.

```
rx = rx2 = 10;
```

This will set both `rx` and `rx2` back to their starting value of 10.